# References for the HVZ theorem?

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics

Is there someone who knows references for a proof of the HVZ theorem in the case of a system of $N$ particles, some of which are fermions?

Comment: Doesn't this belong on the physics site?

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: This question concerns topics that are actually rarely studied by physicists.

Answer (score 1):

All references contain proofs:

- Gustafson, "Mathematical Concepts of Quantum Mechanics".
- Teschl, "Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics" (freely available for personal use from http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-schroe/index.html)
- Reed and Simon, "Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics IV: Analysis of Operators"
- Simon, "Geometric Methods in Multiparticle Quantum Systems", *Commun. Math. Phys.* **55**, 259–274.

Comment: Thank you very much to all. Is the article ""Geometric Methods in Multiparticle Quantum Systems" available online?

Comment: @Fawkes: it appears that your unregistered account has fragmented, which prevents you from commenting on your own question. Please [visit this help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) to get it sorted out.

Comment: @Fawkes: and to answer your question, [all back issues of CMP](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&page=toc&handle=euclid.cmp/1103901018) published before 1997 are available online.